# What is the difference between Bruder and Brüderchen?

Tags: meaning, difference, diminutive

When I look it up, *Brüderchen* seems to just mean *brother*. Then, what's the difference between it and *Bruder*? Why is it spelled with an umlaut and "chen" on the end?

Comment: Welcome! Please see [list of diminutives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language) and take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: In addition to what was already said (using it to define small things), using -chen often defines a more cute version of the word

Comment: Alhough it is of course a standard diminutive, it has some very special occurences immediately coming to mind. Example 1. Grimms' Fairy Tale "Brüderchen und Schwesterchen" (The brother and sister). Example 2. In the variant *Brüderlein* it is well-known in the song "Trink, trink, Brüderlein trink" https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Lindemann_(Komponist)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking its a diminutive that when added to a word (i.e Brötchen) it means a little version of itself.

Answer (score 1):

"*Chen"* is a [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language) ending. If "*-chen*" is added to a word the word becomes neuter and the vowel very often takes an umlaut.

- (der Bruder) **das** Brüderchen - little brother
- (Vogel) Vögelchen - little bird
- (Haus) Häuschen - hut, cabin
- (Brot) Brötchen - bread roll

Another similar diminutive ending is "*-lein*" (der Bruder - das Brüderlein).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like that question, because that could have been answered with a little bit more research

> Why is it spelled with an umlaut and "chen" on the end?

As said in the other answers it's a diminuation of the term *Bruder*.

> Then, what's the difference between it

The semantical nuance for doing this is from *lovingely* to *discriminating*, and totally depends on the concrete context of those siblings talking.

The grammatical building of the *Umlaut combined with -chen* (or *-lein*) is quite regular though.

Answer (score -2):

Most girls say this to there little brother. e.g.
She says that he is her brother to a friend:

> "Er ist mein Bruder"

She says it to him:

> "Bruederchen, kannst du mir Essen holen?"

Comment: That term is neither restricted to _girls (sisters)_, nor saying that for older (regarding _little_) brothers. It's just a _diminuation_, for whatever reasons intended. Your answer doesn't help much in clarification for that question.

Comment: This answer rightfully points out that *Brüderchen* is often used in a vocative function.